# Skills based recommendation system

Tags: classification, predictive-modeling, recommender-system, multilabel-classification

Assuming that I have a list of Users with a list of skills: (each value is a different skill)

[image]

And a list of Tasks with a list of demanded skills:

[image]

Based on a manual classification that returned: (History list)

1. Task1 --> Recommended: User3
2. Task2 --> Reccomended: User5
3. Task3 --> Recommended: User6
4. Task4 --> Recommended: User9
5. Task5 --> Recommended: User8

Given a new Task(6) with skills (A,B,C...):

- What would be the best way or approach to build a recommendation system that learns with past data (history list) and returns a list of the "best ranked" users to perform this Task?

Comment: This is not a recommender system problem. Also in your case what does best mean, what metric are your trying to maximize/minimize ?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to build a learning model?

Your problem seems to be a common [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), all informations are **known**, **absolute** and **deterministic**. You don't need a ML algorithm for this.

Just vectorize your data as one-hot-vectors, define a distance function (you can look to the [Hamming's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)).

Compute the distance vector beetween user/task and pick the one who minimize this distance.